# What happens when we use array[i,j] to access elements in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

In C, to access 2-D arrays, we use the format array[i][j]. But when I accidentally typed array[i , j], it still compiled and returned a small integer value (35 for i = 5 and j = 7 and 0 for i = 5 and j = 8).
I know that for 2-D arrays, using a single [i] will return the address of the ith element, but can the address value be so small even for modern systems with GBs of RAM ? Also, how did GCC compile and interpret [i , j] ?
I'm using GCC with Cygwin terminal on Windows 10 64-bit system.
Here is the statement :

```
printf("\n With maximum weight : %d", table[no_of_items , w]);
```

Comment: [Comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when we use array[i,j] to access elements in c?

`i` is evaluated, then its resulting value is ignored.  `j` is evaluated and used to index `array[]`.  Much like:

```
// printf("\n With maximum weight : %d", table[no_of_items , w]);

(void) no_of_items;
printf("\n With maximum weight : %d", table[w]);
```

`,` used in `no_of_items , w` is the *comma operator*. [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378666/what-happens-when-we-use-arrayi-j-to-access-elements-in-c/52378694#comment91701813_52378666)

---

If `table[]` is a 2D array, `table[w]` in the `printf()` will result in a pointer.  A well enabled compiler will warn.  Perhaps with

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]

```
int table[5][7];
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
printf("\n With maximum weight : %d", table[i,j]);
```

---

> how did GCC compile

Using an unmatched specifier and argument is *undefined behavior* (UB).  The compiler assumed the coder knew what they were doing.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.

> can the address value be so small

Sure, but not so relevant as the mis-match is UB.  What is printed may be the pointer as an `int`, part of the pointer as an `int`, have nothing to do with the pointer, phone number 8675309.  It is UB.